# Best way to have an application-wide array?

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, arrays, static

I have a class which contains a method to download data from my server. This is in the form of JSON, but is parsed and put into an array. As this is a 'model' file, what would be the best way to make it so that multiple 'controllers' can access this data?

Comment: Global variable? Singleton? Property of [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate]?

Comment: Thanks, I'm guessing they all have their pros and cons, so which would be the recommended method?

Comment: I'd advise you to make it a property of your app delegate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hang it off the app delegate, stick it in a global variable, or declare a class method in appropriate spot that returns it.

Better yet, start thinking now about having a proper model layer that, among other things, can manage this data.   That will make refactoring easier in the future as your application evolves.

Comment: By a model layer, are you referring to Core Data?

Comment: Not necessarily;  Core Data is certainly an excellent data persistency tool that I highly recommend.  If you aren't persisting that much data or all of your data is client/server, then -- no -- no need initially.  "Model layer" is a generic term.

Comment: I will be persisting quite a large mount of data from a reasonably complex backend database, so I think core data is the way to go. Thanks for recommending it.

Answer (score 0):

You can create singleton object of class with array object. and by using class method you can get that array any where in app.

e.g.

in Cardnames.h file

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface CardNames : NSObject

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableArray *CardNamesArray;

+(CardNames*) getCardsList;

@end
```

in Cardnames.m file

```
#import "CardNames.h"

@implementation CardNames

@synthesize CardNamesArray;

static CardNames *cards = nil;

+(CardNames*) getCardsList
{
    @synchronized(self)
    {
        if(cards == nil)
        {
            cards = [[self alloc] init];

            cards.CardNamesArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

            /// code to fill array

        }
        return cards;
    }
}
@end
```

and in other classes u can use like this

```
#import "CardNames.h"
.
.
.
NSMutableArray *CardsArray = [[CardNames getCardsList] CardNamesArray];
```